# При компиляции для андроид firebase database перестаёт работать, что делать? Юнити

Tags: unity3d, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

В редакторе всё работает без проблем, но после компиляции для андроид firebase перестаёт работать. Использую юнити, windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, оказывается, чтобы нормально собралось под андроид нужно установить ios